# Learning Pylons - Where to start

Tags: python, pylons, wsgi

I decided to take the leap in to lower level things last night. I've been working with Django for years now, and I feel after all this time that it is simply not made for software outside of the blog/news/social networking sector. Pylons seems to offer flexibility to do anything you want at the expense of being much more complicated to use (at first).

I could take the "Getting Started" tutorial, but I really want to understand more about WSGI and Pylons' general approach. The 5,000 foot view is important to me before I write a single line of code. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend this... http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/#front-matter